# SQL subquery error (figure shown in report is incorrect)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, rdlc

I am doing sql query which is used to retrieve records from database to show in the report. The problem is when I place my calculation as a **subquery**, **SENOKO** column is shown with **redundant** records in every row. I have tested by doing it as a main query, the figure shown in report is correct.

**DO as subquery**

```
SELECT  whbal.customer, customer.imp_license_no,
         (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_good) + 
                     CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_slack)) * 
                     CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.std_weight) / 1000)) 
         FROM whbal 
         INNER JOIN customer ON whbal.customer = customer.customer
         WHERE whbal.warehouse = 'SKW') AS SENOKO
FROM     customer 
INNER JOIN whbal ON whbal.customer = customer.customer
WHERE    (whbal.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2)
GROUP BY whbal.customer, customer.imp_license_no
```

**DO as main query**

```
SELECT whbal.customer, 
       customer.psq_level, 
       SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_good) + 
           CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_slack)) * 
           CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.std_weight) / 1000)) AS SENOKO
FROM   whbal 
INNER JOIN customer ON whbal.customer = customer.customer
WHERE (whbal.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2) AND (whbal.warehouse = 'SKW')
GROUP BY whbal.customer, customer.psq_level
```

Is anyone know what is the problem of my query? Please help and guide
Thanks in advance

Comment: pls show both examples

Comment: first of all, you group by different fields, so results won't be equal

Comment: @jim I had change to the same group by. But the subquery still display redundant record in every row..
Help please..Thanks in advance

Comment: In first case, remove join to customer in subquery and add "and whbal.customer = customer.customer" to subquery where clause. Currently your subquery is not related to main query.

Comment: @Arvo This error is shown: **Column 'customer.customer' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause**

Comment: @Arvo How can I related my subquery to main query? I thought that do a subquery in a main query then is related

Comment: 1. You need to add group by customer.customer to main query (next time don't use same aliases in main and subquery - makes life easier) 2. Just like I said - remove join to customer table from subquery, this way it uses sustomer.customer from main query

Comment: @Arvo I had tried, but the result is still redundant..
And I am not understand why need to group by customer.customer? I alryd group by whbal.customer

Comment: You need to group by subquery correlated field too; whbal.customer is not same field as customer.customer. But if you can't get correct results then something else is wrong - you have multiple whbal records for same customer and same warehouse for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st case you calc SENOKO for every pair customer/imp_license_no of joined tables. In the 2nd case you calc SENOKO for every pair customer/psq_level of the same tables so result rows count probably won't be equal

**UPDATE**
looks like in subquery you don't filter this:
(whbal.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2)

Comment: I had change to the same group by. But the subquery still display redundant record in every row.. Help please..Thanks in advance

Comment: still same group by's.

Comment: What means of still same group by?

Comment: checked, but i alrdy filter it in main query. The subquery should be connect to main query, isn't?

Comment: @user2901955 in your case subquery isn't connected to main query

Comment: So what do u means is I have to duplicate the filtering syntax to my subquery, so that sub and main query can be connected?

Comment: @user2901955 what your 1st query does is: 1) Joins customer and whbal tables and has all that rows
2) For every row from above calcs a sum based on newly queried dataset as whbal-x-customer join. I dont think you need double-filtering. You should simplify task and spell what exactly you want, i can't guess :) Or, if the 2nd query is OK then use it. The queries are different. If you want then skype me "skvoznik"

Comment: I cannot use the 2nd query because I have another condition(warehouse='EKW') so I have to use the 1st query to do, fyi..the 2nd query is do for testing